# Update list item person & group

Tags: workflow

I have two fields in list

1. User email(dropdown)
2. assigned to (person & group)

When I select any option from **user email** and save then automatically assigned to field should be populated with respective email id. Can it be done using `'update list item'` action in designer 2010 workflow.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you open your list as `Infopath` form. Create a secondary data connection for the `second field` or add rule in the `first field` to populate the corresponding data in the `second field` of the list. Follow the following link:

[View the answer in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b8a3e9cc-11d4-4742-b030-2593556cfa52/sharepoint-list-field-should-be-autopopulated-based-on-another-fields-dropdown?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Item Added' receiver.

Comment: Hi,

Can I acheive this through sharepoint designer 2010 workflow?

Event receiver is last option i want to use it SPD doesnot work.